# Function that shows numerical day of month in increments of 7 days (DAY/DATE?)

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula

In each column header I'm looking to display only the numerical day of the first Monday of every week in the year (e.g. January 4, 2021 displays as "4" in a column header) and every subsequent column adds 7 days to that date to display the day of the next Monday.

Adding +7 to the DAY function doesn't work because it adds 7 to the number value and not the date. Any ideas?

For example, the string of column headers would look like 4, 11, 18, 25, 1, 8, 15, etc. (Jan 4, Jan 11, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(
 VALUE("04/01/2021")&":"&VALUE("15/02/2021"))), {"d", "ddd"}), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = 'Mon'")))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(
 VALUE("01/04/2021")&":"&VALUE("02/15/2050"))), {"d", "ddd"}), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = 'Mon'")), 1, COLUMNS(E:BD)))
```

[image]

Comment: If my data is not in row1, but rather row2, how should I adjust this array? I tried a few different options and couldn't figure it out. Also, is the "15/02/2021" in the formula the last date of the array that the formula should calculate for?

Comment: @OhioFarming can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jD-xh66N5le_04C4fkrngb5L1DL_nnAdTD5pqQV-yHk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The range that the formula applies to is E2:BD2 in the spreadsheet